# How can I select other div's child in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select all previous ".pt" when I checked some element.

I tried

```
$('p').mouseover(function(){
$(this).css('font-size', 'bold');
$(this).prevAll('.pt').css('font-size', 'bold');
});
```

In second div, it just changed previous ".pt" in second div.
How can I changed first div's ".pt" even when checked second div element?

```
<div> //first
  <p class="pt p1"></p>
  <p class="pt p2"></p>
  <p class="pt p3"></p>
</div>

<div> //second
  <p class="pt p1"></p>
  <p class="pt p2"></p>
  <p class="pt p3"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try getting the `index` of the element and then [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) with that parameter:

```js
$('.pt').click(function() {
  $('.red').removeClass('red');
  var ti = $(this).index('.pt');
  $('.pt').slice(0, ti + 1).addClass('red');
})
```

```css
.pt {
  padding: 15px;
  background: gold;
  margin: 8px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="pt p1"></p>
  <p class="pt p2"></p>
  <p class="pt p3"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="pt p1"></p>
  <p class="pt p2"></p>
  <p class="pt p3"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.pt').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
  $(this).prevAll('.pt').css('font-weight', 'bold');
  $(this).parent().prevAll().children('.pt').css('font-weight', 'bold');
});

$('.pt').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.pt').css('font-weight', 'normal');
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>first</h3>
  <p class="pt p1">paragraph</p>
  <p class="pt p2">paragraph</p>
  <p class="pt p3">paragraph</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>second</h3>
  <p class="pt p1">paragraph</p>
  <p class="pt p2">paragraph</p>
  <p class="pt p3">paragraph</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```